# button click event with get datepicker value is old on bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap-datepicker component.When I change 'other', change 'day' again but I get datepicker value is old(select 'other' datepicker value) by Button click event.

**My code:**

```
    $('#date').change(function (e) {

        switch (this.value) {
            case 'day':
                $("#dpform").val(showdate(-1));
                $("#dpdend").val(showdate(0));
                $('#dpform').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#dpdend').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                break;
            case 'week':
                $("#dpform").val(showdate(-7));
                $("#dpdend").val(showdate(0));
                $('#dpform').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#dpdend').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                break;
            case 'month':
                $("#dpform").val(showdate(-30));
                $("#dpdend").val(showdate(0));
                $('#dpform').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#dpdend').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                break;
            case 'other':
                $("#dpform").val(showdate(0, 'other'));
                $("#dpdend").val(showdate(0, 'other'));
                $('#dpform').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#dpdend').removeAttr("disabled");
                break;
        }
   })
```

**//showdate method**

```
function showdate(n, string) {
    var uom = new Date();
    uom.setDate(uom.getDate() + n);

    if (string == "other")
        uom = uom.getFullYear() + "-" + (uom.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + uom.getDate();
    else {
        uom = uom.getFullYear() + "-" + (uom.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + uom.getDate() + " " + uom.getHours() + ":" + uom.getMinutes() + ":" + uom.getSeconds();
}

    return uom.replace(/\b(\w)\b/g, '0$1');
}
```

**//button click event**

```
$('.btndataquery').click(function () {
    var a = $("#dpform").val();  //a,b value is old
    var b = $('#dpdend').val();  
    //TO DO ...
});
```

my html code:

```
<select id="date" name="date" class="span2">
    <option value="day" class="btn-date">Last one day</option>
    <option value="week" class="btn-date">Last one week</option>
    <option value="other" class="btn-minimize-other">other</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btnQuery" value="Query" class="btn btn-success btndataquery" name="assign" />

<div class="other-search" style="display: none;">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">
        <b>time form:</b></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="dpform" class="width100" />
            <b>to</b>
            <input type="text" id="dpdend" class="width100" />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't follow you, Can you provide more details?

Comment: Please re-write what's the problem and your question

Answer (score 1):

on button click or some other event if you want change anythings in exciting Date-picker value then try below snipcode

/* HTML part */

/* Jquery part */
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(startDate));

$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(endDate));

$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(startDate));

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. but if I understood you, here's a *dirty* trick.

```
$('.btndataquery').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
       var a = $("#dpform").val();
       var b = $('#dpdend').val();  
       //TO DO ...    
    }, 50);  //Delay 100 milliseconds, so values aren't old
});
```

We're adding a delay so the values are not old.

Please use this very carefully, it's *dirty*.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I think you don't understand what I mean.I debuged and found '#date' change event datepicker value is right,but 'btndataquery' click event datepicker value is previous.